# Prove that ax+bx+ay+by ≤ 300.

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

Let $a,b,x,y$ be positive numbers satisfying:
$ax ≤ 100,  bx ≤ 100$,
$ay ≤ 100,  by ≤ 50$.
Prove that $ax+bx+ay+by ≤ 300$.

Can someone help me ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three cases, according to the position of $a$ viz $b$
and $2b$.

**Case 1.** $a \leq b$.

Then 
$$
(a+b)(x+y) \leq (a+b)(\frac{100}{b}+\frac{50}{b})=150\frac{a+b}{b} \leq
150\frac{b+b}{b}=300.
$$

**Case 2.** $b \leq a \leq 2b$.

Then 
$$
(a+b)(x+y) \leq (a+b)(\frac{100}{a}+\frac{50}{b})=
150+\frac{100b}{a}+\frac{50a}{b}=
300-\frac{50(a-b)(2b-a)}{ab} \leq 300.
$$

**Case 3.** $2b \leq a$.

Then 
$$
(a+b)(x+y) \leq (a+b)(\frac{100}{a}+\frac{100}{a})=200\frac{a+b}{a} \leq
200\frac{a+\frac{a}{2}}{a}=300.
$$

Comment: How did you get 50(a−b)(2b−a)/ab?

Comment: @user128687 If you put $t=\frac{a}{b}$, in case 2 $t$ is between $1$ and $2$. The problem is then reduced to the optimization of a polynomial of degree $2$ in $t$, and the maximum is attained on the extremities, $1$ and $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume without loss of generality that $a\le b$ and $x\le y$

$$ax+by\le 100+50=150 $$

By the rearrangements inequality,

$$ay+bx\le ax+by\le150$$

Adding both, we are done.

Comment: I don't think you can assume that WLOG, because the problem is not symmetric in $a$ and $b$ and in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Ragnar oh you're right. any thoughts?

Comment: Mathematica's maximize functions finds approximately $290$ at $a=x=10$ and $b=y=\sqrt{50}$. Maybe you can do some ugly optimization, but I don't want this problem to be calculus (instead of an inequality).

Comment: @Ragnar my proof still works for $a\ge b$ and $x\ge y$. But I dont want it to be proof by cases.

Comment: Tell me more details.

Comment: + a>= b and x >= y can be cases.